# how to handle event callbacks in jabber.net within ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, xmpp

I would like to create a web project using ASP.NET MVC 4 which aims to make use of XMPP for some of its messaging, I have good knowledge of `Jabber.net` however, what I am a little confused about is the threading model I need to implement to use this type of library with an MVC application.

For example, when a user clicks a button on my page, on the server side, I want to:

1. connect to the XMPP server
2. then authenticate
3. then send an IQ message
4. then receive a response back

After all this is done, I then want to send the HTTP response message back to the client.

All of this is done using standard event handlers within `Jabber.net` but this model doesn't traditionally fit with web based threading, unless I am just tired and missing something...

Should I use a `WaitHandle` to stop the controller thread until the other threads are done with the `Jabber.net code`, then respond?

Do the async controllers fit here?

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't want to use Strophe since it's a web project?

Comment: This could be a good option, my reason would be that I didn't know it existed :) I will have to get back to you on its suitability across the whole project though

Comment: I have blogged here about ASP.NET MVC XMPP web clients with MatriX and SignalR. Yuu can use also jabber-net or agsXMPP instead of MatriX:
http://www.ag-software.net/2012/08/20/web-clients-with-matrix-and-signalr/

Comment: Just wanted to update you guys, so far I have been playing with Strophe and its working, but I think this thread has changed its focus from the original question, so I might start a new thread soon on Strophe and XMPP if need be. I would still like some information on the original question though...